# free Proxy switching software which will let me surf with different Proxies

Tags: firefox, proxy, switch

I have seen many Questions on  the super User regarding Proxy Switching But none of the software helped me.
I have used

- [Elite Proxy Switcher](http://www.eliteproxyswitcher.com),
- Proxy Switcher Standard
- [easy Hide Ip](http://www.easy-hide-ip.com)
- Hide Ip easy

But easy hide ip and Hide ip easy,both support specific numbers of proxies provided by the developer.
Elite Proxy switcher,Proxy Switcher Standard supports Unlimited free proxies have trial period of 15 days.

Is there any Free Software which is available or anybody has used ?

Software should allow me to **add free proxies available on various sites** like www.hidemyass.com etc and If possible should be **compatible with Firefox** .

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Firefox, have you considered one of the many proxy switching extensions? [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) seems like it would meet your needs.

[image: FoxyProxy]

Comment: tried foxyProxy.but it doesn't helping me a lot...i  have to enter each proxy in IP:PORT Format manually..its doesn't have **import Proxy** Function yet...if u could provide any desktop application ,,that would be very helpful..anyways thanx